# How to sum up rows in excel using VBA

Tags: vba, excel, sum

I'm creating my first module, using VBA, and not sure how to sum up rows.  I was wondering if someone could help me.  I have a file of transactions, picture attached:

[image]

I'm trying to insert a break (blank row) in between date groups (group all transaction from a specific date), and then a sum of each total in the break under each column for the corresponding date.  My code is as follows, but I'm stuck on how to create the sum as I'm not sure the syntax.  Here is the code I came up with:

```
    Sub InsertRowsBetweenDates()
'
' InsertRowsBetweenDates Macro
' Insert Rows in between two dates that are not equal
'
Dim x As Integer
Dim y As Integer
Dim row1 As Range
Dim row2 As Range
Dim t As Integer 'tracking how many cells to add together


'define x as cell row value
x = 2
'define y as cell row value
y = 3
'start tracker at 0
t = 0
'row 1 and row 2 get their values
Set row1 = Cells(x, 4)
Set row2 = Cells(y, 4)

'Do until there are no more entries in the worksheet (or really until row 1 has no value)
Do Until row1.Value = False
    x = x + 1
    y = y + 1
    Set row1 = Cells(x, 4)
    Set row2 = Cells(y, 4)
    t = t + 1

    'If row 1 and 2 don't equal each other, insert a row above row 2
    If row1 <> row2 Then
        row2.EntireRow.Insert Shift:=xlDown

        'sum up t rows for subtotal and tax [THIS IS WHAT IM STUCK ON]


        'skip the break            
        x = x + 2
        y = y + 2
        Set row1 = Cells(x, 4)
        Set row2 = Cells(y, 4)
        t = 0

    End If
Loop

End Sub
```

As you can see, I got the break to work, albeit it only works for this file as the rows and column positions are hardcoded, but its a start.  At this point I have a tracker to track how many rows have been counted, and I think I just need to insert code to sum up the rows.  How would I go about achieving this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're heading completely at the wrong path. 
I wouldn't do that unless I totally and utterly HAVE TO

Why?

Because you're putting the data together with the report. What happens when someone need to insert a row? What happens when someone has to maintain your code?

Look at the following options:
 1. Use the source as a [table](http://www.contextures.com/xlExcelTable01.html) and summarize with a [pivot table](http://www.contextures.com/xlPivot01.html)
 2. Add a column and use the [SUMIF](http://www.contextures.com/xlFunctions01.html) function

These ways you avoid using VBA altogether and still manage to get the reports you need. Good luck!

Comment: thanks, my excel knowledge is very limited so I know nothing about pivot tables, and didn't know about sumif... I'll read up on it and try it out!  Definitely easier than trying to code without that knowledge as well!

Comment: after playing around with only the table link you sent me, I've already solved the issue with filters and the total row, although I can't view them all at the same time which will be a little annoying... I'm going to check out the other two links to see if I can get all totals to display at the same time (without the filter), thanks for your help!  Scrapped VB module, haha, it was fun though....